# Replacing a certain text in SQL using Python

Tags: python, sql, regex

I am using Python to replace certain string in sql file that I have. The string looks this:

```
<img title="\frac{3}{8}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dpi{50}&amp;space;\fn_phv&amp;space;\frac{3}{8}" alt="" />
```

Basically it contains a html code for a fraction. But now I would like to replace it with:

```
<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>
```

To replace it in the sql file, I am using this code in Python,

```
for line in filedata:
    re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", line)
```

This doesn't change the data, so I have tried this as well.

```
filedata1 = re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", filedata)
```

This also didn't help me. Need some help on this.

My full code:

```
import re
with open('/Users/cnnlakshmen/Downloads/qz_question.sql', 'r') as fin:
    filedata = fin.read()

for line in filedata:
    re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", line)

filedata1 = re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", filedata)
print filedata1

# Write the file out again
with open('/Users/cnnlakshmen/Downloads/qz_question1.sql', 'w') as fin:
  fin.write(filedata1)
```

Each data line looks like this:

```
(163, 'S001', 'T005', 'ST015', 'Medium', '1', 9, '1', '<p>The ratio of the number of children to the number of adults at a funfair was 2 : 5.​&nbsp;&nbsp;<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>5</sub>of the children were boys. If there were 120 more adults than children, how many girls were there at the funfair?</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>', 'without_image', '[{"value":"16","answer":"0"},{"value":"40","answer":"0"},{"value":"64","answer":"1"},{"value":"120","answer":"0"}]', '<p>5 -2 = 3</p>\n<p>3 units --&gt; 120</p>\n<p>1 unit --&gt; 120 &divide; 3 = 40</p>\n<p>2 units --&gt; 40 x 2 = 80</p>\n<p>1 - <img title="\\small \\frac{1}{5}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\small&amp;space;\\frac{1}{5}" alt="" width="5" height="20" />&nbsp;=&nbsp;<img title="\\small \\frac{4}{5}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\small&amp;space;\\frac{4}{5}" alt="" width="4" height="16" /></p>\n<p><img title="\\small \\frac{4}{5}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\small&amp;space;\\frac{4}{5}" alt="" width="4" height="16" />&nbsp;x 80 = 64</p>', 'lakshmen K', NULL, '1', '0', '2015-05-03 15:54:19', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not working as you might think it is working.

```
>>> a = '<img title="\\frac{3}{8}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\dpi{50}&amp;space;\\fn_phv&amp;space;\\frac{3}{8}" alt="" />'
>>> pattern = r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>'
>>> re.findall( pattern, a)
[('3', '8')]
```

This extracted the digits of your fraction. Now, this works in finding the string,

```
>>> pattern = r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{\d+\}\{\d+\}"[^<]*>'
>>> re.findall( pattern, a)
['<img title="\\frac{3}{8}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\dpi{50}&amp;space;\\fn_phv&amp;space;\\frac{3}{8}" alt="" />']
```

Also, change your replace string to make your method work.

```
>>> sub = "<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>"
>>> re.sub(pattern, sub, a)
'<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with `r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>'` failed due to two reasons:

1. To match a `\`, the pattern must contain an escaped `\`, i. e. the data line part `\\frac` is matched by the pattern `r'\\\\frac'`.
2. Differing from what you wrote at the top how the string looked (`title="\frac{3}{8}"`), the data line you provided at the bottom of the question had `title="\\small \\frac{1}{5}"` - you didn't account for the `\\small` also in the pattern.

Incorporating that into your pattern yields

```
    r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")(?:\\\\small )?\\\\frac\{(\d+)}\{(\d+)}"[^<]*>'
```

and matches your data.